# How to extract "Date column" value for a specific file for Windows 7 x64, in C++

Tags: c++, windows, date, stat

I want to extract the **Date** value for a specific file and compare it with Date Modified and Date Created, in Visual C++.

I've seen that I can extract **Date Created** and **Date Modified**, but I don't know anything about **Date**.

I've altered some files with a buggy software, and the only column that still has a valid time is the **Date** one. How can I extract it?

I'm using Windows 7 x64.

Here, I've seen only **st_atime, st_ctime, st_mtime**:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx

Comment: There are different kinds of "file date": date created, data last modified, date last accessed.  I believe that when most people think of "file timestamp" or "date", they generally mean "date modified".  IMHO...  For Windows, you might try [GetFileTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Windows 7 has a column called simply "Date". In my situations, this one remained unaltered, pointing to the actual creation date of the file. Date Created and Date Modified, have been altered to the moment when the files was moved with the buggy software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows stores three timestamps for each file or folder:

- Creation time (the time/date the item was first created)
- Last modification time (the time the file was last written to)
- Last access time (the time the file was last accessed)

There are a number of ways to read these timestamps, but using the native Win32 API you can do the following:

```
LPCWSTR pszFileName = L"c:\\path\\to\\myfile.txt";
WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(pszFileName, &wfd);
if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    FindClose(hFind);
    // timestamps can now be found at:
    // wfd.ftCreationTime
    // wfd.ftLastAccessTime
    // wfd.ftLastWriteTime
}
```

You can use functions like `FileTimeToSystemTime()` to convert the `FILETIME` values (which are simply a tick count since a specific date) into more usable `SYSTEMTIME` structures which give you day, month, year, hour, minute, etc.

*Note: "Last modification time" is also updated for folders, as well as files, and indicates the last time a file was modified directly inside that folder. Changes to folder timestamps are not propagated to parent folders.*

*Note 2: "Last access time" is more or less deprecated, and is disabled by default in newer versions of Windows. You can enable it using a registry setting.*